# Menu pull down when mouse over

Tags: menu, drupal-7

I build a site in Drupal7,
How can I post a menu bar that open a sub menu just in the mouse over on?
There is a module for it in the Dropal.org site?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these modules to get you started: http://megadrupal.com/blog/7-mega-menu-modules-for-drupal

Answer (score 0):

You can use Superfish Menu Module.